# Failed to resolve import

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

Here is the error which is showing up for Vue Vite:

> Failed to resolve import "./components/SiteNavigtation.vue" from "src\App.vue". Does the file exist?
>
> import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
> 2  |  import SiteNavigtation from "./components/SiteNavigtation.vue";

I got this error while locating the file from my Component > SiteNavigation.Vue! While it says the above mentioned error.